# Support for VMware checks was not compiled in zabbix 3.0.7

Tags: vmware-esxi, zabbix

I recently deployed Zabbix 3.0.7 and i am facing an issue when trying to monitor VMWare ESXi 5.5 hosts through SNMP.

"Support for VMware checks was not compiled in."

This happens for some itens, like CPU Usage and others, but the datastore free space for example is working just fine.

I am using Zabbix VMWare built-in template.

[Please take a look on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq3pG.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to recompile Zabbix with libxml2 and libcurl support, that is using `--with-libcurl --with-libxml2` arguments to `configure`.

Answer (score 0):

So , please upgrade your VMWare to 6.0. But VMWare license under 6.0 doesn't supported anyone zabix licence.

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain better?

Comment: Yep , i installed zaabix 2 monts ago in my Server host VMWare ESXi 5.5. But i don't finished this process becouse my VMWare was too old. I upgrade version to ESXi 6.0 and zaabix go run. :)